# Pandas normalize dataframe by iterating over all columns but index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to perform a normalization of a dataframe, contatining one index column and other columns with numeric values.

```
Index    a     b      c
xy1     555   436    3667
xz2    4626   658    463
xr3     425   674    436
bx4    4636   6567   6346
```

I want to perform max-min normalization on the dataframe, drop columns containing NaNs, and return the normalized dataframe with the original index.
I'm thinking of something like this, but how can I exclude the index column from the loop, so that it stays the same in the returned dataframe?

```
def normalize(df):
    result = df.copy()
    for feature_name in df.columns:
        max_value = df[feature_name].max()
        min_value = df[feature_name].min()
        result[feature_name] = (df[feature_name] - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
        if result[feature_name].isnull().values.any():
            result.drop([feature_name], axis=1, inplace=True)
            print(f'Something wrong in {feature_name}, dropping this feature.')
    return result
```

Comment: `df = df.set_index('Index')`?

Comment: I'm not following. When you iterate over `df.columns` it returns the Index? Or you have a column named "Index"? In the latter case, `if feature_name == "Index": ; continue` to skip it.

Comment: I messed this up, sorry, I'm not too familiar with pandas yet! I was assuming that iterating over df.columns would return Index as well, but as you pointed out, it doesn't. Anyway, your suggestion was useful because there was another column I wanted to skip, so I could use it for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your implementation of `min-max` scaling:

```
s = df.set_index('Index').dropna(axis=1)
s = (s - s.min())  / (s.max() - s.min())
```

Or, you can use `MinMaxScaler` from `sklearn.preprocessing`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

s = df.set_index('Index').dropna(axis=1)
s[:] = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(s)
```

---

```
print(s)

              a         b         c
Index                              
xy1    0.030872  0.000000  0.546701
xz2    0.997625  0.036209  0.004569
xr3    0.000000  0.038819  0.000000
bx4    1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
```

Comment: I tried that, but I didn't know how to manage columns containing NaNs this way, so I went for the explicit loop over the columns.

Comment: @Carlo Not sure what you mean by `manage columns containing NaN's` but i guess using `.dropna(axis=1)` will remove the columns that having one or more `NaN` values.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself clearly. The problem is that there were a few columns containing NaNs AFTER the normalization, so in my loop I'm checking for that and eliminating those columns.
As a matter of fact, I'm noticing now that I could prevent this altogether, since it appears the NaNs are simply due to some columns containing always the same value (so that s.max and s.min are the same). Once I remove those, the normalization does not produce NaNs anymore, and I can go with your approach :)